# nim nimscript is not executing commands

Tags: nim-lang

nim script is not executing commands

Nim Compiler Version 0.12.0 (2015-10-27) [Windows: i386]
Windows 7

given the file
server.nims:

```
mode = ScriptMode.Verbose
exec "gcc -v"
```

started with:
`nim e server.nims`

is just printing:

```
[NimScript] exec: gcc -v
```

but it seems not to execute anything.
If i execute `gcc -v` in cmd.exe it shows gcc's version string.

what is the correct way to run it?

Comment: It may be an old bug. I have 0.12.1 (2015-11-28) and it does what it is suppose to do using your code. Try to upgrade your compiler.

Comment: I've installed 
Nim Compiler Version 0.12.0 (2015-12-15) [Windows: i386]
via git. 
Now my code works.
If you write this as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be an old bug. I have 0.12.1 (2015-11-28) and it does what it is suppose to do using your code. Try to upgrade your compiler.